# Try to display list of item base on Id but i get error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display list of item on my view by take string id as parameter.

This is my table data

[image]

and I simply create a browse action, it will take `ApplicationUserId` as parameter and return list of `AppFunctionId` to the view.

Here is my action code:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string id)
{
    var result = db.UserFunctions
                   .Where(a => a.ApplicationUserId.Equals(id))
                   .Include("AppFunctions")
                   .Select(a => a.AppFunction.Name).ToList();

    return View(result);
}
```

And this is my view:

[image]

After put id value to browse action I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Does anyone know which part of my code is wrong? Why do I keep getting this error saying different type of dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your code is, in your linq lambda expression, you are selecting `a.AppFunction.Name`. By selecting it, the result list becomes a list of type string.

What you should do is just remove the select clause. It will still include the AppFunctionName since you already have an Include clause.

```
public ActionResult Browse(string id)
{
   //remove select clause
   var result = db.UserFunctions
   .Where(a => a.ApplicationUserId.Equals(id)).Include("AppFunctions");

   return View(result);
}
```